# Rendering a React component using ES generator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, generator

I have a very basic implementation of a sleep function which resolves a promise after x miliseconds:

```
module.exports = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

I then need to render a React component in an ES6 Stateful Class Component after the sleep, but this sadly throws the error: `Objects are not valid as a React child`. Is there something wrong with this generator implementation?

```
import sleep from './sleep';
class Dummy extends React.Component {

  *renderSubComponent(arg) {
    yield sleep(1000);
    return (<ChildComponent {...arg} />);
  }

  render() {
    return (
     {this.props.check ? this.renderSubComponent(this.props.check).next() : null}
    );
  }

}
```

I can not use async/await.

Comment: Iterators return an object of the form `{value: ..., done: ...}`. The call `this.renderSubComponent(this.props.check).next()` will return something like `{value: somePromise, done: false}`. You *could* access `.value`, but it wouldn't help much since you cannot render a promise. This approach won't work.

Comment: small notice: shouldn't : `*renderSubComponent(arg)` be `*renderSubComponent(...arg)` and  `return (<ChildComponent {arg} />);` ?

Comment: on top of what @FelixKling points out, there's no real connection between the promise and the returned component, so even if you work out the promise in some way the design seems flawed

Comment: @FelixKling ok thanks. Would using a .then method on the promise be better? I don't see how I would approach it differently to get the sleep result that I want.

Comment: @NightKn8 it's purely mocked for this example. It has different naming in development.

Comment: What you were actually looking for is `async`/`await` (use it with a transpiler if you cannot directly) - do not use generators. In any case, neither of them is a tool that makes asynchronous code synchronous; that is impossible.

Comment: You should not call asynchronous methods from `render`. What did you expect this component to do, freeze your screen for a second?

Comment: If you want to "update" the component after the same time, you have to approach this in a completely different way. E.g. the component could have an initial state of `renderSub: false`. Then when component is mounted, start a timer (your sleep thingy). When that's finished, set the component's state to `renderSub: true`. That will cause the component to rerender (update). Inside the `render` function, render `ChildComponent` if `this.state.renderSub` is `true`.

Comment: Your approach would never have worked because `render` is synchronous.

Comment: @FelixKling In the end I was able to solve it with just CSS animations but your comments pointed me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can't make this implementation because the generator returns an iterator and if don't program the iteration then nothing will happen.

A more reasonable solution for this will be using the component's state so you can keep the state in the same component and then you can mutate it

This is how the component will look like

```
class Dummy extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.setState({
      renderSubComponent: false,
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        renderSubComponent: true,
      });
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    const { renderSubComponent } = this.state;
    let subComponent;

    if(renderSubComponent) subComponent = (<ChildComponent check={this.props.check} />);

    return (
      <div>
        {subComponent}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can set initial state to false in the constructor instead of setState there, but yeah this is the right idea